# Fetch Products under a specific Environment in an Organization - Apigee Edge

Tags: apigee, apigee127

I am trying to fetch all the Products which are associated to an Environment under an organization.

I am able to fetch all the products in an organization but i don't seem to find a way in getting Environment specific Products.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order to effectively help we'll need to see your code, your output, and your expected output. You can read [ask] if you need guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You might think the 'Search API Products' API call would facilitate this, but I cannot make it work either. Docs: https://apidocs.apigee.com/management/apis/get/organizations/%7Borg_name%7D/apiproducts

e.g., curl -X GET https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/organizations/{my_org}/apiproducts?attributename=environments&attributevalue=prod

Answer (score -1):

You can try putting the full URL after GET inside quotes ('') and it will work with curl

Comment: This looks more like a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60823179/2227743) rather than a new answer.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the answer. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, Given that, can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing and why you believe it is the best approach?